# Zyxel as slave router

Tags: windows, networking, router

Let my first start by apologizing for not knowing the correct terminology in networking. It was not my main field in school. I have a home setup where I have:

- Cable network modem Cisco EPC3828D, which provides internet
- Zyxel NBG-418N v2 WiFi router which provides WiFi and has 4 LAN ports
- A table PC and a laptop

My table PC is connected to Cisco via LAN cable, Cisco is connected to Zyxel via LAN cable and laptop is connected to Zyxel via LAN cable. I need to make these two work in the same network, mainly Windows Home Network and connect to each other via browser ip address because my laptop hosts a local development environment for programming.

Cisco works in IP 192.168.0.1, while ZyXel works in 192.168.1.1. I can't seem to get access between these two computers after attempting to shut off DHCP in Zyxel and changing it's IP address because every router has it's own configuration panel and I can't figure it out. Can anyone explain the basics of how I can achieve the network?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the answer after just doodling in Zyxel's configuration menus. Found a page where I just set the router as Access point and changed the IP configurations etc. Works now as intended.